# First-order model theory problem

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

Are the following structures isomorphic?

a) $(\mathbb{R};=;+)$ and $(\mathbb{Q};=;+)$; 
b) $(\mathbb{Z}, <)$ and $(\mathbb{Z},>)$; 
c) $(\mathbb{N}, <)$ and $(\mathbb{N}, >)$;

Comment: What do *you* think?

Comment: @lemontree, I personally think that (b, c) are indeed isomorphic, while a - is NOT

Comment: There's an important difference between b) and c). Why do you think $\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb Q$ in a) are not isomorphic? (That's actually correct, btw.)

Comment: @Berci, there are issues with $\sqrt{2} \in \mathbb{R}$ for instance, however do not see any major difference between (b) and (c)..

Comment: Ok. I suggest to try to find explicit isomorphisms. You should be able to do that for b), and update your question with your attempts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your intuition is somewhat correct:

a) No. An isomorphism would require a bijection of sets, but the cardinalities of $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ are different (the former is countable, the later is not).

b) Yes. Let $f: \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ be the map $f(x)=-x$. This is clearly a bijection of sets, and also an embedding of structures as:
$x < y$ iff $ -x > -y$, i.e. $(x,y) \in   <$ iff $ (f(x),f(y)) \in   >$.

c) No (assuming equality is a logical symbol). Call the first structure $N_1$, and the second $N_2$. Suppose that they were isomorphic. Then they would satisfy the same sentences. But $N_1 \models \exists x \forall y (x \neq y \implies (x<y)$ (take $x=0$), and so $N_2 \models \exists x \forall y (x \neq y \implies (x>y)$. This is a contradiction as $\mathbb{N}$ has no upper bound, so the two structures can't be isomorphic.